# Calling gracefulStop Singleton Actor

Tags: singleton, akka, akka-cluster

For testing purposes, I'm trying to restart a singleton actor (created using `ClusterSingletonManager` and `ClusterSingletonProxy`). However, the documentation for `gracefulStop` says:

> **IMPORTANT NOTICE:** the actor being terminated and its supervisor being informed of the availability of the deceased actor’s name are two distinct operations, which do not obey any reliable ordering. Especially the following will NOT work:

```
def receive = {
    case msg =>
        Await.result(gracefulStop(someChild, timeout), timeout)
        context.actorOf(Props(...), "someChild") // assuming that that was someChild’s name, this will NOT work
}
```

Does anyone know a way around this? Please don't tell me to use `Thread.sleep`. A blocking loop that checks for the name availability would be OK, though a less hack-ish way would be preferable. If that's the only way, how can one check if an actor name is available?